# Javascript - Changing text on event object's sibling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

I am trying to get my js to work for my website so that when a user selects a file to upload the text on the button that is sibling of the event caller will change. Unfortunately I can't get it to work and because of my inexperience in js I can't come up with a better way. My best approach got it working but the text changed on every button that had a file input. Can someone please help me out? Here is my setup and my coffee code:

EDIT WITH FIX:

In the view:

```
.assets-fields.pull-left.span3
  - count=0
  = f.simple_fields_for :assets do |builder|
    - if builder.object.new_record?
      .file-wrapper.pull-left
        .btn.btn-warning
          %span.icon-camera
          .photo-text{:id => "asset_#{count}"} Choose a Photo
          - count = count + 1
          = builder.file_field :photo
```

In my js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $("input:file").change (event) ->
    idOfInput = event.target.id
    console.log idOfInput
    idOfSibling = $('#' + idOfInput).prev().attr('id')
    console.log idOfSibling
    $('div#' + idOfSibling).text("Photo Selected!")
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

`idOfButtonSibling.text` is a function

```
$(idOfButtonSibling).text("Photo Selected!")
```

Answer (score 0):

idOfButtonSibling is an array of all the siblings of idOfInput. You have to select a single element before you change the text.

I would recommend you to assign unique IDs to each buttons and use them to refer to particular button.

Try this but this is not a good practice:

```
$(idOfButtonSibling[0]).text = "Photo Selected!"
```

or,

```
$(idOfButtonSibling[1]).text = "Photo Selected!"
```

or

```
$(idOfButtonSibling[2]).text = "Photo Selected!"
```

and so on...

Comment: All good now, will update to show my results in case someone needs it in the future!